# Создать декоратор кэширования

Tags: python, python-2.x

Задание:

Чтобы сделать код ниже, создайте параметризованный декоратор с именем «caching».
Пусть он принимает тайм-аут в качестве аргумента для сохранения возвращаемых значений.

Вопрос:

Не могу понять как воспользоваться `time.sleep(SLEEP_SPAN)` что бы:
`Driver1` и `Driver2` получили одинаковый `id`, а `Driver3` получил другой `id`.
В моем декораторе `Driver2` и `Driver3` получают одинаковый `id`, `Driver1` получает другой `id`.

```
import random
import time

def caching(timeout):
    _results = {}
    def decor_func(func):
        def wrapped():
            if timeout in _results:
                return _results[timeout]
            else:
                _results[timeout] = func()
                return func()
        return wrapped
    return decor_func

# === do not modify below ===
SLEEP_SPAN = 3


def _users_slow_selector():
    time.sleep(SLEEP_SPAN // 2)
    return random.randint(0x5000, 0x10000)


@caching(timeout=SLEEP_SPAN)
def get_driver_id():
    return _users_slow_selector()


@caching(timeout=SLEEP_SPAN)
def get_passenger_id():
    return _users_slow_selector()


driver1 = get_driver_id()
passenger1 = get_passenger_id()

driver2 = get_driver_id()
passenger2 = get_passenger_id()

assert driver1 is driver2, "Drivers differ, but should be same!"
assert passenger1 is passenger2, "Passengers differ, but should be same!"

# Exhaust the caching timer
time.sleep(SLEEP_SPAN)

driver3 = get_driver_id()
passenger3 = get_passenger_id()

assert driver2 is not driver3, "Drivers are same, but cache should have been expired and you get a new one!"
assert passenger2 is not passenger3, "passengers are same, but cache should have been expired and you get a new one!"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут мы помещаем в словарь(кэш) `id` и `time.time`. Таким образом словарь(кэш) перезаписывается после каждого превышения `timeout`. Что позволяет нам засекать время между выполнения функций каждый раз с нуля, а не продолжать подсчет времени.

```
def caching(timeout):
    cache_results = {}

    assert isinstance(timeout, int), "Wrong type, expected <type 'int'>, got {}.".format(type(timeout))
    assert timeout > 0, '"timeout" must be bigger 0, got {}.'.format(timeout)

    def param_decorator(func):
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            key = func.func_name
            if key in cache_results and cache_results[key][0] + timeout >= time.time():
                return cache_results[key][1]
            else:
                value = (time.time(), func(*args, **kwargs))
                cache_results[key] = value
                return value[1]

        return inner

    return param_decorator
```

Answer (score 1):

Мы знаем что `driver1` и `driver2` должны получить одинаковый `id` (условие прописанно в `assert ...`. Создаем `id` c ключем `key1` и помещаем в словарь (кэш). Возвращаем его `driver1`, если между `driver1` и `driver2` `time.sleep` меньше `timeout`, то присваиваем такой же `id` и берем его сразу из словаря (кэша) что бы не ждать очередной `time.sleep`, иначе если между `driver1` и `driver2` или между `driver2` и `driver3` `time.sleep` больше `timeout` то создаем новый `id` с ключем `key2`. Так как между `driver1` и `driver2` `time.sleep=1 < timeout=3`, то `driver1` и `driver2` получают одинаковый `id`, а между `driver2` и `driver3` `time.sleep=4 > timeout=3`, то `driver3` получает `id` по ключу `key2`.

```
def caching(timeout):
    start = time.time()
    _results = {}

    def decor_func(func):
        def wrapped():

            if 'key1' not in _results:
                _results['key1'] = func()
            finish = time.time()
            time_ = finish - start
            if time_ < timeout:
                return _results['key1']
            elif time_ > timeout:
                _results.update({'key2': func()})
                return _results['key2']

        return wrapped

    return decor_func
```

Comment: Не очень понятно что тут происходит, могли бы написать в ответе? Про `key1` и `key2` тоже интересно узнать )

Comment: Спасибо, что расписали :) Только такое лучше в сам ответ включать (кнопка `править`), а то видишь просто кусок кода, а для чего он и что делает непонятно :)

Comment: Понял вас. Учту в дальнейшем.

Answer (score 0):

```
def caching(timeout):
    start_func_time = time.time()
    _results = {}

    def functional_utils(fn):
        def inner():
            if start_func_time + timeout < time.time():
                _results.clear()
            fn_name = fn.__name__
            if fn_name not in _results:
                _results[fn_name] = fn()
            return _results[fn_name]

        return inner

    return functional_utils
```

Comment: `fn_name = fn.__name__` можно и не использовать -- ключем словаря может быть и сама ссылка на функцию, т.е. `fn` -- `_results[fn]`

Comment: Согласен. Ключем может быть все что угодно. Во 2 примере это показано.